Can I use IfSubStr to search pgf key values that contain footnotes?
I would like to search some pgfkeys values for particular substrings.  My attempt to locate such functionality in the manual didn't pan out, so I turned to using "\IfSubStr" from xstring.  Provided I've set things up correctly, there seems to be a problem with both parnotes' "\parnote" and memoir's "\pagenote" being read from the key value by "\IfSubStr".
My understanding of how LaTeX works is still poor -- I tried throwing in a few instances of "\protect", but to no avail.
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[symbol]{parnotes}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{xstring}
\makepagenote
\pgfkeys{
    /Tom/.initial=,
    /Dick/.initial=,
    /Harry/.initial=,
}
\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{
    /Tom={This is about Tom.},
    /Dick={This is about Dick.\parnote{This is a \texttt{parnotes} ``parnote'' about Dick.}},
    /Harry={This is about Harry.\pagenote{This is a \texttt{memoir} ``pagenote'' about Harry.}},
}

\pgfkeysvalueof{/Tom}

\pgfkeysvalueof{/Dick}

\pgfkeysvalueof{/Harry}\\

``Tom'' contains ``om'':
    \IfSubStr {\pgfkeysvalueof{/Tom}} {om} {True} {False}

``Tom'' contains ``homas'':
    \IfSubStr {\pgfkeysvalueof{/Tom}} {homas} {True} {False}

``Dick'' contains ``ick'':
%   \IfSubStr {\pgfkeysvalueof{/Dick}} {ick} {True} {False}

``Dick'' contains ``oc'':
%   \IfSubStr {\pgfkeysvalueof{/Dick}} {oc} {True} {False}

``Harry'' contains ``arry'':
%   \IfSubStr {\pgfkeysvalueof{/Harry}} {arry} {True} {False}

``Harry'' contains ``airy'':
%   \IfSubStr {\pgfkeysvalueof{/Harry}} {airy} {True} {False}

\parnotes
\printpagenotes

\end{document}

I tried adding "\noexpandarg" before "\IfSubStr", after seeing a similar question come up before posting.  Although that allowed compilation to complete, it prevented the true/false query from answering correctly.  (Arguments expansion in IfSubStr)  Another solution mentioned there was using the starred version of "\IfSubStr", but that resulted in another failure.
I'm open to alternatives, too.  I just went with xstring because it looked simple enough for my use.

Can you explain a bit more what you want to use this for? It seems like a bit of an XY problem.

I don't know what you mean by "an XY problem", but my usage is simple:  I have much data structured in the form of PGF keys and values, and in certain cases I'd like to be able to search a given key value for a fragment of text.  The key value might be an integer, or even a series of paragraphs with formatting, footnotes, etc.  I need something that can search the key value's text (or at least the non-footnote portion of it) for a matching phrase.

An XY problem just means you're asking about your solution to a problem rather explaining what larger problem is. In particular this seems like a very odd use of pgfkeys, so maybe there's a better way to store things to begin with that would make the searching problem more tractable.

I require the utility of a database key/value system that will, while providing an option for someday importing a database, still allow me to edit things file-by-file without a database.  It would be an uphill battle for me to learn something non-pgfkeys, now, but I'm open to suggestions.

You may want to learn the Expl3 methods provided by the LaTeX kernel. See the documentation here. I think this would ultimately be much simpler to deal with than using pgfkeys for this.

Thanks for the suggestion, but I think you mistake me for someone who is actually capable of learning how to program!  I'm just an end user who copies and pastes examples, with no real understanding of how things work.  Now, maybe that should be a clue to me that I've reached my limits and had better hire a professional instead, but that's not really an option, presently.  If anything, I'll just forego the string search in favor of setting certain variables by hand.

An alternative approach (possibly expl3 as Alan Munn suggested) would, in the end, provide you with far more powerful tools for what you want to do and avoid a lot of frustration in the long run. Using pgfkeys as a pseudo-database is rather strange and not at all something the package is designed for. It will be slow, awkward and likely require you to tangle with TeX's innards to an extent unlikely to provide an easy path to success.
If you really want to do this and you are adamant about using pgfkeys and xstring, then it can be done. But I somehow doubt it will provide the solution you wanted in the end.
Caveat emptor!!
xstring provides starred versions of macros, as explained in a later section of the manual which discusses features for programming. This allows you to process arguments as-is because they are first rendered harmless.
\IfSubStr* {<stuff-to-test>} {airy} {True} {False}

There are some caveats to the use of the starred versions, which you should be aware of. See the manual for details.
These macros allow us to test for the presence of a sub-string in the value of the key even if it contains things like \parnote or new lines. To do that, though, we first need to get the key's meaning and provide it with some protection.
We can use get to retrieve the key's value. This gets rid of the complexities of the key machinery, which just makes it more difficult to figure out expansion issues.
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{/Dick}{\Dickvalue}

But we don't want to pass \Dickvalue as-is to the test because we know how that will end. Instead, we want to pass the meaning of \Dickvalue i.e. what it expands to, but we don't want it to get expanded any further. So, we need something like
\pgfkeysgetvalue{/Dick}{\Dickvalue}
\IfSubStr*{\expandafter\noexpand\meaning\Dickvalue} {ick} {True} {False}

\meaning\Dickvalue gives the meaning of the macro. Once we have that, we don't want it to expand further, so we need \noexpand\meaning\Dickvalue. But, of course, that's not right. That will stop \meaning expanding, while \Dickvalue tries to expand and it all ends in tears. So we want \noexpand to expand after \meaning. Hence, \expandafter\noexpand\meaning\Dickvalue.
You can also store the meaning in a macro for convenience if, say, you want to use it several times.
\edef\DickValue{\expandafter\noexpand\meaning\Dickvalue}%
\IfSubStr* {\DickValue} {oc} {True} {False}


expl3 abstracts from a great deal of the messiness at the TeX level, so that it is far less often necessary to control expansion yourself. Whether this method is easier for you than the more formal syntax I don't know, but if expl3 counts as 'programming', I suspect this does, too. The difference may be the level of familiarity. If you are accustomed to seeing \expandafter etc., expl3's syntax will look like a bug-eyed monster. All I can say is that, despite appearances, the bug-eyed monster is really quite cooperative, so don't let the alien appearance intimidate you. At the same time, there is a learning curve, so if you're comfortable with TeX's \expandafter and friends, you can certainly manipulate the keys' values, albeit with rather more trouble.
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[symbol]{parnotes}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{xstring}
\makepagenote
\pgfkeys{
    /Tom/.initial=,
    /Dick/.initial=,
    /Harry/.initial=,
}
\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{
    /Tom={This is about Tom.},
    /Dick={This is about Dick.\parnote{This is a \texttt{parnotes} ``parnote'' about Dick.}},
    /Harry={This is about Harry.\pagenote{This is a \texttt{memoir} ``pagenote'' about Harry.}},
}

\pgfkeysvalueof{/Tom}

\pgfkeysvalueof{/Dick}

\pgfkeysvalueof{/Harry} % Don't end lines with \\

``Tom'' contains ``om'':
\IfSubStr {\pgfkeysvalueof{/Tom}} {om} {True} {False}

``Tom'' contains ``homas'':
\IfSubStr {\pgfkeysvalueof{/Tom}} {homas} {True} {False}



``Dick'' contains ``ick'':
\pgfkeysgetvalue{/Dick}{\Dickvalue}
\IfSubStr*{\expandafter\noexpand\meaning\Dickvalue} {ick} {True} {False}

\edef\DickValue{\expandafter\noexpand\meaning\Dickvalue}%
``Dick'' contains ``oc'':
\IfSubStr* {\DickValue} {oc} {True} {False}


``Harry'' contains ``arry'':
\pgfkeysgetvalue{/Harry}{\Harryvalue}
\edef\HarryValue{\expandafter\noexpand\meaning\Harryvalue}%
\IfSubStr* {\HarryValue} {arry} {True} {False}

``Harry'' contains ``airy'':
\IfSubStr* {\HarryValue} {airy} {True} {False}

\parnotes
\printpagenotes

\end{document}

I can't help thinking it would be easier to just grep the files of data, but perhaps I just don't understand the use-case well enough. [I am not going to say that you could doubtless do this with Lua because I'm not a programmer and I don't understand it. However, it does let you search for sub-strings and is available if you use LuaTeX as your engine.]

Note that I should probably delete this immediately and almost certainly will end up deleting it later. I currently seem to delete more answers than not.

Thanks, the \noexpand and \expandafter trick worked.  I've seen use of those before, but I would never have guessed to try both or where to place them.

Can either your or Mr. Munn point to an example of the LaTeX3 stuff being used in a situation similar to mine?  Maybe it's something I could pick up in time, and so I should look further into it, but for the time being I'm going to have to proceed with how I have things currently.

"Using pgfkeys as a pseudo-database is rather strange and not at all something the package is designed for."  By the way, what is pgfkeys meant for?

@user182238 Primarily to provide a way of parsing options specified by users in <key>=<value> format, particular in pgf, tikz and related packages, which allow you to create diagrams and pictures in TeX/LaTeX/ConTeXt. It can also be used to process class and package options, for example, or to provide a key-value interface for arbitrary uses in documents. As such, it isn't intended to be optimised or really designed to hold large amounts of data. pgf generally is slow. expl3 has a range of features explicitly designed for storing data of various kinds.

@user182238 Neither of us has any specific example to hand and we're not entirely clear what your intended use is in the end. But we were both thinking that property lists would be a better structure than pgfkeys. And it would not be difficult to set that up for simple usage.
